# Consuming SP2010 Search Service application in SP2013 farm - Certificate exception

Tags: search, enterprise-search

I am trying to establis trust relationship between SP2010 and SP2013 environment

Steps have been followed as per following URL -

- http://gbois.com/view/1019/SharePoint-Steps-to-Consume-Search-Service-App-from-2010-in-2013
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashishranjan/2014/10/29/consuming-sp2013-search-on-sp2010-farm-a-step-towards-moving-to-sp2013/#comment-105
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/09/03/cross-farm-service-applications-integration-between-two-separate-sharepoint-farms/#comment-15395

Everything works fine till Step 3. In Step 4, we need to consume SP2010 published search service application in SP2013. When I try to do that, I get following error in Central Admin UI –

```
Unable to connect to the specified address. Verify the URL you entered and contact the service administrator for more details.
```

I checked ULS logs and found following error –

```
An exception occurred when calling SPTopologyWebServiceApplicationProxy.EnumerateSharedServiceApplications on service https://SP_2010_Server:32844/Topology/topology.svc : System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'SP_2010_Server:32844'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

It looks like SP2013 environment is not able to trust SSL certificate of SP2010 environment.

I verified following things –

- SP2010 root certificate is already imported in SP2013 central admin
  under Security 
- Manage Trust Firewall ports are open for 80, 443,
  32843, 32844.
- Ensured that access to SP2010 Topology service is
  granted to SP2013 farm (as mentioned note after Step 5)

I further tried following things –

- Manually adding SP2010 root certificate to trusted root authority.
  Did not help.
- Manually adding SP2010 certificate (for topology.svc)
  to certificate store.

Did not help either.

One important thing to note is that our SP2010 and SP2013 environment are in different domains.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to crawl SharePoint 2013 farm in SharePoint 2010, AFAIK this is not gone happen. 2010 farm can be consumer not publisher for 2013.

> Note. This only works one way and a SharePoint 2013 farm can not
>   consume services from a SharePoint 2010 provider).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alimaz/2012/08/07/service-application-federation-between-sharepoint-2013-public-preview-and-sharepoint-2010/